# Get Latitude Longitude from address in php

Tags: php, geocoding, google-latitude

I am developing an mobile application for ANDROID and IOS. I want to get **latitude , longitude from address** pass by application to API. Which Google API is use for getting latitude and longitude from address and Also let me know is there any **daily limit** for calling API per day in php and android and ios.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous">

            // get you address field
            var city = document.getElementById("home_city_select").value;

            var jsonLtdLng="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+city+"&key=API_KEY";

            $.getJSON(jsonLtdLng, function (data) {
              console.log(data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
            console.log(data.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
            });
</script>
```

Comment: This does not answer OP's original question

Comment: Adarsh asked two questions second part of question was already answered I answered the first part.

Comment: I want php code not javascript code, because I have to use it in controller on in javascript file